# How do I compare data in a List to Data in a DataView?

Tags: c#

I have a `DataView` containing Data, I need to compare the DataView to a `List<string>` and get only Data from the `List<string>` that is not in the `DataView`. The List is populated using a `ListBox`.

*Here is the List:*

```
    //Populate List<string> from ListBox
    private void LoadList()
    {
        var vehicle = new List<string>();
        var model = new List<string>();


        foreach (ListItem automobile in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            var components = automobile.Value.Split('\\');

            vehicle.Add(components.First());

            model.Add(components.Last());
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < vehicle.Count; i++)
        {
            // Compare items in List<string> to DataView
            // Get Data from List that is not in DataView
        }

    }
```

This `ListBox` and `List<string>` before and after.

[image]

*The DataView data structure:*

The `Vehicle` and `Model` are both `Primary Key` (Composite).

[image]

*This is the DataView member:

```
    private static DataView LocalDataView { get; set; }
```

How do I compare the List against the DataView and get only the Vehicle and Model from the List that does not exists in the DataView?

Comment: DataView is UI compnent?

Comment: I am referring to the `DataView` Class: The Data above is from the Database which populates the DataView. I only have access to the DataView and have to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
list.Except(LocalDataView.Select(x => string.Form("{0} {1}" , x.Vehicle, x.Model).ToList());
```

Comment: Referencing the link, it appears I have to place the `DataView` in another List? I am using two separate list for the Vehicle and Model.

Comment: You want to compare which list with DataView? In question you show only a list that contains Vehicle & Model

Comment: There are two list: `var vehicle = new List<string>();` and
        `var model = new List<string>();`. Both list are used because we are splitting the `ListBox` items.

Comment: so you want compare which one? vehicle or model?

Comment: Both: I need to make sure the Model and the Vehicle does not exists in the DataView. So Both Lists.

Comment: You can use Except to find which one not exist in DataView, But should do separately